# Google Map API v.3 Drawing library: fireing events during editing polylines

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-maps-api-2, polyline

I am porting app from API v.2 to API v.3

App have function that allows user to draw a polyline. Every time new vertex is inserted path length is updated. How to do it in v.3 as drawing library has events only on "polylinecomplete".
Editing events described [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays#user_editable_shapes_events), may be used only on existing polylines. This do not make me happy as I can receive my polyline object only when drawing is done...

```
    google.maps.event.addListener(drawingManager, 'overlaycomplete', function(event) {
        if (event.type == google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.POLYLINE) {
            my_polyline = event.overlay
            drawingManager.setMap(null);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is quite old. Just in case someone falls into the same problem :
[The editing event api](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays#user_editable_shapes_events) is plenty usefull :

```
google.maps.event.addListener(your_polyline.getPath(), 'insert_at', function(index) {
// Do what you like when you insert a new point on your polyline here.
});

google.maps.event.addListener(your_polyline.getPath(), 'set_at', function(index) {
// Do what you like when you move an existing point on your polyline here.
});
```